# Due to small innodb_buffer_pool_size MySQL returns wrong results without any warning

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance

I've table like this:

```mysql
CREATE TABLE `offers`
(
    `id`          int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `description` text,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
```

And running query like this:

```mysql
SELECT count(*) AS count, description
FROM offers
GROUP BY description
HAVING count >= 2
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

returns result in which some rows have count equals to 1.

I've discovered than when I increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from `128M` to `256M` it solves this issue.

I can understand that my query is too memory consuming to be done with smaller memory limit.
However, how is it possible that MySQL **silently** returns wrong results without any warning/error?
I've checked error `log_error` file and didn't find any warnings/errors about wrongly performed query.

**EDIT: How to reproduce**

Tested on: Ubuntu 18.04 64bit & MySQL 5.7.31

1. Create a database

```mysql
CREATE DATABASE bug CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

2. Download database dump: https://f001.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v1/b2_download_file_by_id?fileId=4_z3eec3c1800331e85734f0b1b_f100d6e61629f98fe_d20200822_m211237_c001_v0001144_t0019
3. Unzip and import dump into created database.
4. Run the query

```mysql
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM test
GROUP BY description
HAVING count >= 2
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

5. See some rows where count is equal to 1. In my case those rows don't start at the beginning but e.g on row 23.

Comment: the problem is the TEXT and missing INDEX

Comment: look into th error log regular there it should appear a message

Comment: Can you provide some records! I test it and it works fine. SQL doesn't return Wrong result except you write wrong query due to your business.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: @nbk - Indexes are for performance; they are not required for correctness.

Comment: Please generate a reproducible case and file a bug at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: Added info about OS version & MySQL version. Also added how to reproduce this bug.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL team has confirmed that this is a bug which needs to be fixed.

More info: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100610